# Margin for overflowing text in new line

Tags: html, css

I have Html like below

```
<h4 class="clickbelow">This is very long line. Which overflows to new line when width is small.</h4>
```

Below is the css I used

```
.clickbelow:before {
    content: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBFti.png");
    top: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
```

So When the text is overflowing to the new line, I want the second line text to be of same margin as of first line. Right now its under the `content image`.

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/hdbwkcmq/

Comment: Please add a working example on for example JSfiddle.net or Codepen. Also, please rephrase your question, because it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Is there a reason for why you are using `content`? Or would it be fine if this was achieved in some other way?

Comment: is this what you wish to achieve? http://plnkr.co/edit/Z1m7dOAYe6NDPsZl9RSI?p=preview

Comment: @Shivi : exactly . Please answer it so I can approve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following plunk helped the user achieve what he wished to.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Z1m7dOAYe6NDPsZl9RSI?p=preview

I added the following changes to css:

```
.clickbelow:before {
    content: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBFti.png");
    top: 0;
    left: -8px;
    position: absolute;
}

h4{
  padding-left:25px;
  position:relative;
}
```

EDIT: made minor changes to the css itself.

Comment: @Vishnu: r u getting that image? The one thats there in content? That image is not rendering for me. And somehow, I dont see even the ::before working for me for the fiddle.

Comment: No i dont see...will try in plnkr

Comment: @Vishnu: yeah... just try it in plunkr, or maybe create a local html file, and try it in there... N lemme know if it still doesn't work out...

Comment: @Vishnu: i just made some changes. Sorry about it. can you give it a try now?

Comment: @Vishnu: no problems... :)

Answer (score 1):

The `:before` CSS-3 feature set the content, like it says, before the regular content.

**I think there are 2 possible ways:**

*First with a bullet list:*
use `list-style-image` to set the image and and style the font as H4 with an extra css class `.like-h4`.

*Second: use an extra container:*
around the h4 you can set an extra container with the image only and an `padding-left` of the image width.